# MVC Redirect with headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In an action method I want to redirect to a third party url. They collect some info from custom headers.

I have understood that I can not redirect the user, for example:

```
return RedirectResult(some url);
```

since the browser will not reattach my custom headers..

How do I do this? Is this a wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

> They collect some info from custom headers.

So you can't redirect. You need to read their documentation. You're most likely expected to do an HTTP request to their server and show the user the response.